# how to avoid stack overflow exception in this code?

Tags: c#

I got `StackOverflowException` in my code

```
 public int Movie_ID
 {
     set
     {
         if (value == 0)
         {
             throw new Exception("value cannot be empty");
         }

         Movie_ID = value;
     }
     get
     {
         return Movie_ID;
     }
 }
```

> Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."}

Comment: public int MovieID
        {
            set
            {
                value = r1.Next(1, 10);
                MovieID = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return MovieID;
            }
        }

Comment: By using a backing field, for example.

Comment: `return Movie_ID;` calls `Movie_ID;` which calls (via property) `return Movie_ID;` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Your get keeps calling itself recursively. You need to create a backing field and return that value, not call the property again. e.g:

```
private int _movieId;

public int Movie_ID
 {
     set
     {
         if (value == 0)
         {
             throw new Exception("value cannot be empty");
         }

         _movieId = value;
     }
     get
     {
         return _movieId;
     }
 }
```

Comment: side note: `throw new Exception("value cannot be empty");` is *evil*; `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), "...")` or alike

Comment: And if you are checking the value anyway, is negative allowed?